# How can I use addEventListener('dblclick', (event) to open a modal in a webApp?

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

My web extension is supposed to open up a modal when someone clcks

```
//Open the AI modal
const myModal = document.querySelector('modal-dialog');
const callMyAi = document.querySelector('body');
callMyAi.addEventListener('dblclick', (event) => {
  

  // Check if a double-click event is attached to the element
  if (callMyAi.ondblclick) {
    // Do nothing.
    console.log('This element has a double-click event attached.');
  } else {

  }
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Mean something like this?

```
window.open("https://your.link","Your Window Name", "left=100,top=50,height=600,width=800");
```

More details here: [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)